# Manage processes on an distributed windows computer system

Tags: windows, windows-services, daemon, distributed-computing

I want to manage the startup / re-start and shutdown of a multi module software system running on a set of windows machines.

For example:

- [some machines booted, some still doing so]
- run the whole system using a startup-process or a network command etc. an the operator station computer - all machines shall start it's defined processes
- some processes may crash during operation - if defined, they shall be restarted silently
- stop the whole system using a stop-process or a network command etc. an the operator station computer - each machine kill the defined processes
- goto [start]
- the state of the processes of each machine can be queried, using a web-interface or such.

For now I'm using a system of batch files and remote-execute/kill, which is error prone as hell.

So I plan to develop a kind of system service running in the background and maintain the state of the processes.

But maybe somebody knows some tool which already does the things I need.

Thank you in advance!